# "PROGRAMMING KEYS" Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 / Mac Mini OS X 10.9.5

Tags: mac, keyboard, microsoft

I used to have my up and down arrow keys in the Microsoft keyboard programmed to "send backward" or "bring forward" when using InDesign on my Mac. Somehow I set it back to default settings (so they now move things up and down). How can I reprogram them? I checked the Apple menu>system preferences>keyboard and didn't see those keys listed. I also tried apple menu>system preferences>microsoft keyboard. I assume it can be done here but I can't figure out how. Can someone please explain to me in detail? BTW I'm not great with computers or computer lingo so be very detailed and speak in layman's terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try **https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/**

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe apps have their own Keyboard Shortcuts setup, in the Edit menu.

I don't have InDesign, only Photoshop, but this is what it looks like in there…

It's in Layer > Arrange [you need to do a lot of scrolling to get there]

[image]

After comments…

It may not be possible to assign a single-key shortcut in Adobe, it may always need to include  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  
however, you could perhaps do the equivalent in
System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > App Shortcuts
by assigning each one to 'All Applications' - which will then work in any app that actually has that precisely-worded command…

[image]

Comment: Yes. I tried that in photoshop. It wouldn't allow me to select the arrow key(s). In InDesign I can't even figure out how to find the option "send backword" or "send forward".... Also, I am positive that isn't how I did this before because once those keys were assigned, they performed that function in every program I have.

Comment: ah, OK, that makes me think you did it a different way - see my edit.

Comment: Ok I tried that,

Comment: Looked good but didn't change anything... I'd add a screen shot but this won't allow me to.; No way to attach